# Added Listener to button which is dynamically createing?

Tags: java

I have problem, i dynamically create the buttons (users write text in JtextArea then is create the new button) and  when user clicked in button this text is writing in JtextPane.
I dont know why doing this?
The buttons is created but when user clicked on button doing nothing.

```
DODAJNOWYButton.addMouseListener(new NewMouseListener(textPane1) {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            String text = textArea2.getText();
            bar.add(new JButton(""+text));
            bar.validate();
            bar.repaint();

            try{ 
               doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),""+text,null);

            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
               System.out.println(e);
            }
            super.mouseClicked(e);

        }
    });
```

Comment: If you want the new buttons to do something when clicked, you need to add an ActionListener to them (or a MouseListener as you already do in your example)

Comment: yes i know, i do this when i create button

Comment: You don't. You create a new button at the 5th line in your code, then you don't add any listener to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use addClickHandler():

```
JButton yourButton = new JButton(""+text);
yourButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
          //do something
        }
 }
```

Comment: i dont know names of new buttons

Comment: Changed my answer to fit your comment